# wordpress and future posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to show future posts in all posts list on page.

my code

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 10,
               'category' => $category->cat_ID );
                            ?>

<?php $posts = get_posts($args); ?>
```

what arguments I can to write for showing all posts from category with future posts?

And it my archive page code, what should to show posts list from category

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

this solution mast to show future and past posts too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the `post_status` to be `publish` and `future` in your `$args`, for example:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'category' => $category->cat_ID,
    'post_status' => array(
        'publish',
        'future'
    )
);
```

To get the posts with these args, use (for example):

```
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

To display these posts, use (for example):

```
foreach( $posts as $p ) {

    // display the post title
    echo '<h2>' . apply_filters('the_title', $p->post_title) . '</h2>';

    // display the post date
    echo '<h4>' . date('F jS, Y', strtotime($p->post_date)) . '</h4>';

    // display an excerpt of the post
    echo wp_trim_excerpt($p->post_content);
}
```

An alternative is to use query_posts / WP_Query to get these posts. In this case, to display the posts, you would use a loop, similar to the one in your question. Such example can be seen here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop

Comment: I have edited my answer above to show you some example code to achieve this.

Comment: In IE if I try to open sheduled post I get the 404 error. In other browsers all ok